Visual Studio Code Cleanup: How to avoid removing unassgiend/unused variable when file is on save
I am using Code Cleanup in Visual Studio and noticed when file is on save.
The unused variable will be removed like:

I tried editing the .editorConfig file but it didn't seem to work with any of the setting options.
Does anyone know a trick to remove this default setting?
The following screenshot is based on the first answer but it was not working


Did you ever resolve this problem? I'm running into the same issue, where removing it from the Included fixers doesn't stop it from removing unused variables.

In Visual Studio, if you want to avoid deleting unassigned or unused variables when saving a file, you can try the following steps:
Tools > Options > Text Editor > Code Cleaning > Configure Code Cleaning, you will see the following window, select according to your needs:

If your Remove unused variables are in Included fixers, then unused variables will be removed when saving:

You can try moving the Remove unused variables from the Included fixers to the Available fixers below and see if that works.
Please remember to check Run Code Cleanup profile on Save:

Here is a demo example:
1: After I create the following sample project, enter Code Cleanup, and then check Run Code Cleanup profile on Save:

2: Move Remove unused valriables from Available fixers to Included fixers:

3: After clicking save, you can find the unused variables: int unusedVariable = 10; will be removed:

4: Undo the operation, revert to the previous code, and move Remove unused valriables to Available fixers:

5: After clicking save, you can find the unused variables: int unusedVariable = 10; still exists:


Did you actually try it and see if it's working?

Yes, I tried it and it works. I added some clarifications to my answer, you can check it out.

Thanks for your answer. Please add a screenshot or refer to the example I addedd to the question

Do you mean to ask me to give you a screenshot of the whole operation? I've added an example to the answer, and you can see what I've updated.
